# coin/ sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

You flip a coin two times. You consider two events:

$$A=\{ " it \ lands\ heads \ up \ two \ times"\}$$

$$B=\{ " it \ lands\ tails\ up \ two \ times"\}$$

Which events do I have to add to get an sigma-algebra F?
Firstly, it should be $ \bar{A} \in F$  and  $ \bar{B} \in F$
So I have to add $$\bar{A}= \{ (t,h),(h,t),(t,t) \}, \ \bar{B}= \{ (t,h),(h,t),(h,h) \}$$ The last ones are already in F.
Is this enough, when I consider the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $F$ satisfying $A,B\in F$ we first construct the collection: $$\mathcal V=\{A\cap B,A\cap B^{\complement},A^{\complement}\cap B,A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}\}$$It is evident that every element of $\mathcal V$ is an element of $F$.

Further the elements of $\mathcal V$ are mutually disjoint and cover the whole space.

Then: $$F=\{\cup\mathcal A\mid\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal V\}$$

Or in words: elements of $F$ are exactly the sets that can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal V$.

Usually (not always) $\mathcal V$ has $4$ distinct non-empty elements and consequently $F$ has $2^4=16$ elements.

---

edit:

with order:

- $A\cap B=\varnothing$
- $A\cap B^{\complement}=\{(h,h)\}$
- $A^{\complement}\cap B=\{(t,t)\}$
- $A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}=\{(h,t),(t,h)\}$

Then we find the following unions:

- $\varnothing$
- $\{(h,h)\}$
- $\{(t,t)\}$
- $\{(h,t),(t,h)\}$
- $\{(h,h),(t,t)\}$
- $\{(h,h),(h,t),(t,h)\}$
- $\{(t,t),(h,t),(t,h)\}$
- $\{(h,h),(t,t),(h,t),(t,h)\}$

Comment: When I don't conisder the order, then I have only 8, haven't I?

Comment: $8=2^3$ is correct here. It finds its cause in the fact that $A\cap B=\varnothing$ in your case so that $\mathcal V$ contains $3$ disjoint **non-empty** sets (and next to that also the empty set). Then there are $2^3$ possible unions. Order is not relevant here.

Comment: Ok. The tasks says, that I have to consider the order and don't consider the order. In one case I have 8 elements in F. In the other case 16.

Comment: I dont' get to 8 elements: $A \cap B= \emptyset$ , $ A \cap \bar{B}=A =(H,H)$, $ \bar{A} \cap B=B =(T,T)$ $ \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}=(Z,K),(K,Z)$

Comment: $A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}=\{(h,t),(t,h)\}\neq A$ (with order). There are $3$ disjoint non-empty sets in $\mathcal V$. This also if order is disregarded (i.e. $A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}=\{\{h,t\},\{t,h\}\}=\{\{t,h\}\}$). In both cases the answer is $2^3=8$.

Comment: I don't get that I have: $$ F= \{  \emptyset \{(H,H)\}, \{(Z,Z)\} , \{(T,H)\} , \{(H,T)\} , \{(H,H),(T,T),(H,T)(T,H)\}                         $$ What is missing?

Comment: Do you agree with my edit?

Comment: Yes, only one question. Why don't I consider for example $\{ (h,t)\} $ as single element?

Comment: There is a distinction between *outcomes* $(h,t)$ and *events* $\{(h,t)\}$. An event is a *set of outcomes*. In the special case that an event only contains one outcome it is still preferred to maintain that distinction. Just more handy and avoiding confusion. That's why we have outcome $(h,t)$ and singleton event $\{(h,t)\}$. The probability measure is formally defined on events (not on outcomes).

Comment: I understand that, but I still don't get why I can't consider $\{(h,t)\}$ as singelton event. Why does it make more sense to put $\{(h,t)\}$, $\{(t,h)\}$ together. Or has this something to do with F. Otherwise it isn't a sigma algebra?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add one more event, namely $\overset {-} A \cap \overset {-} B=\{(h,t),(t,h)\}$. The sigma algebra is $F=\{\emptyset, A, B ,A\cup B, \overset {-} A,\overset {-} B,\overset {-} A\cap \overset {-} B,\{((h,h),(t,t),(h,t),(t,h)\}$.

Comment: Ok then I have  $F= \{ \emptyset, \bar{A}, \bar{B}, \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}\}$ But there have to be 8 elements in this set?

Comment: $F=\{\emptyset, A, B , \overset {-} A,\overset {-} B,\overset {-} A\cap \overset {-} B,\{((h,h),(t,t),(h,t),(t,h)\}$.

Comment: But this are only 7 elements in F?

Comment: @drhab Thanks for pointing out.